# Consider a trait as a subclass of another class

Tags: scala, instance, require, traits

my question below is definately a nonsense but answering it will help me for another problem.
How force a trait to be mixed only by a specific class (or its subclass). I thought about use require() inside it :

```
abstract class Aclass(c_attribut1 : Int){
  var attribut1 : Int = c_attribut1

  def getAttribut1() : Int = this.attribut1 
}

class Bclass extends Aclass(1) with Trait1{

}

class Cclass extends Aclass(2) with Trait1{

}


trait Trait1{
  require(this.isInstanceOf[Aclass]);

  def f() : Int = this.getAttribut1() * 2 // it obviously does not work
}
```

Then, I don't know how considere Trait1 as a Aclass (in order to avoid asInstanceOf every where). I know the function f should be in the Aclass but, as I said, I would like to know how properly force a trait to be mixed by a specific class and how to get messages of this class in the trait.

I wonder this because I need a trait is mixed by a specific class with template :

```
trait TraitBuiltHost extends Observable{
  require(this.isInstanceOf[BuiltInfrastructure[_ <: TraitHostDefinition]]);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self typing:

```
class MyClass1
class MyClass2

trait MyTrait {
  self: MyClass1 =>
  val i = 1
}

scala> new MyClass1 with MyTrait
res0: MyClass1 with MyTrait = $anon$1@3f0762f6

scala> new MyClass2 with MyTrait
<console>:1: error: illegal inheritance;
 self-type MyClass2 with MyTrait does not conform to MyTrait's selftype MyTrait with MyClass1
              new MyClass2 with MyTrait
                                ^
```

See also **Self references** part of [`scala` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/info).